# How to extract a specific element value from an array in laravel controller

Tags: laravel-8

I do have the following output in the form of an array

```
$fetchSubFormDetailData = $this->PMSDS11FetchSubFormDetailTrait($request);
echo 'Data Submitted' ;
print_r($fetchSubFormDetailData);
```

The result shown because of print_r is as under

Data SubmittedArray
(
[LineId] => 10
[IncomeTo] => 500000.00
)

Now I want to extract IncomeTo from this array into a variable in this controller for validations. I tried using the following ways

```
$IncomeTo = $fetchSubFormDetailData[0]->IncomeTo;
```

I am keep on getting the following error in laravel8.

"message": "Undefined array key 0",
"exception": "ErrorException",

How can I extract the value (500000.00) of IncomeTo element from this array in my $IncomeTo variable?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$IncomeTo = $fetchSubFormDetailData['IncomeTo'];
```

Comment: Bingo,
This works. Tried everything except this.
Thanks a ton bro.
Cheers

Comment: If its good, mark it as the answer.  Good luck!